# Why don't we make object for datetime class while calling now()?

Tags: python, python-datetime

So here is the code

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

While we know that the second datetime is the class, why haven't we made the object first from the datetime class such as `d = daytime()`?

And then call the `now()` method present in that class?

Like this `d.now()` or `datetime().now()`?

Comment: You can declare a variable with like, current_datetime = datetime.now(). But, if you see most developers does in a way just like you pointed out means, they might have to get the exact times or prevent themselves from reusing the the datetime variable, which wont give the current time.

Answer (score 0):

The `now()` method is a class method of the the `datetime` class.  Class methods offer alternative ways to instantiate the class and return an object.

In the case of `datetime.now()`, the class method instantiates a `datetime` object with the current time stamp and returns it.  Even after instantiating a `datetime` object, the `now` method still references the class.

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

# d is a datetime object with the current timestamp
d = datetime.now()

sleep(3)

# d2 is *different* datetime object with the current timestamp, 3 seconds later
d2 = d.now()
```

Comment: Thx but then to pull out the attributes such as date it should b datetime.date rather than datetime.now().date I guess all variables r also static?

Comment: Also when we make object of datetime a=datetime (year,month day time) if we print (a) it returns year month day time while normal instantaneous object reference var only return s memory location why?

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.now()` is a classmethod. This means it operates on the class itself, not its instance.
It wouldn't make sense for it to be an instance method - it creates a completely new object that only relies on 1 factor, and that is current time.